# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061) and Database is already loaded

Tags: python, mysql

Here is my Error

```
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(msg=exc.msg, errno=exc.errno,
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)
```

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='admin', password='admin',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='sciencefair')
print(cnx)
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Is your MySQL service started?

Comment: try to `telnet localhost 3306` to check if the port is connectable

Comment: check if service is running or not? if yes then try to connect with MySQL client first.

Comment: So I realized that this code would probably be better:
```import mysql.connector as mysql
db = mysql.connect(host=".", user="admin", password="admin")
cursor = db.cursor()
```
But it shows this error:

Can't open named pipe to host: .  pipe: MySQL (2)

Comment: @nay where do I enter `telnet localhost 3306` ?